# `push label` pushs [label], not the address of label (Rust asm!)

Tags: rust, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm writing an OS. I use `asm!` macro to change the code segment.  (Details on 2020/06/08 changes to `asm!` [here](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2020/06/08/new-inline-asm.html) and in [Rust RFC 2873](https://github.com/Amanieu/rfcs/blob/inline-asm/text/0000-inline-asm.md))

```rust
pub unsafe fn set_code_segment(offset_of_cs: u16) {
    asm!("push {0:r}       // 64-bit version of the register
    lea rax, 1f            // or more efficiently, [rip + 1f]
    push rax
    retfq
    1:", in(reg) offset_of_cs);
}
```

This works. However, if I use `push 1f`, the address of label `1:` will not be pushed. Instead, it will be a memory source operand, loading from `[1:]`

So the following code

```rust
pub unsafe fn set_code_segment(offset_of_cs: u16) {
    asm!("push {0:r}
    push 1f           // loads from 1f, how to push the address instead?
    retfq
    1:", in(reg) offset_of_cs);
}
```

will not work. Disassembled (by `ndisasm`) code is this:

```
11103   │ 0000B9EC  57                push rdi
11104   │ 0000B9ED  FF3425F6B90080    push qword [0xffffffff8000b9f6]
11105   │ 0000B9F4  48CB              retfq
```

---

The desired code written in nasm syntax is this:

```
    [bits 64]

    extern set_code_segment

set_code_segment:
    push rdi
    push change_code_segment         ; absolute address as a 32-bit immediate
    retfq
change_code_segment:
    ret
```

Linked with the kernel (and `extern "C" { pub fn set_code_segment(offset_of_cs: u16) -> () }`), the code works. The address of `change_code_segment` will successfully be pushed.

So my question is: why `push 1f` of `asm!` pushes the content of address `1:`, not the address of `1:`?

Comment: AFAIK, Rust's inline assembly draws some inspiration from GCC. So perhaps you need to use the `$` prefix to specify that you mean an immediate operand: `push $1f`

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your comment, but `push $1f` didn't change the situation... The disassembled code was the same.

Comment: Separate possible problem:  You take the new CS as a `u16`; make sure you still use a qword push, not a push of a 16-bit register!  `retf` still does two 64-bit pops.

Comment: For your actual problem, LEA + PUSH is what you want to do, so you can use a RIP-relative addressing mode for the LEA.  In GNU `.intel_syntax`, it would be `lea rax, [RIP + 1f]`, with square brackets.  IDK if that's the syntax Rust asm uses or not.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, actually I push `u16` into `rdi` and this works. Surprisingly, using a 16-bit register doesn't work.

Comment: `push di` only changes RSP by 2, not 8.  IDK what part of that you find surprising, but the possible operand-sizes for `push` in 64-bit mode are word and qword.  (16-bit push is almost never what you want.)  I was worried that Rust *would* pick a 16-bit register since the Rust value was a `u16`; that's what GNU C inline asm would do for a `short` or `uint16_t`.  But yes, fortunately it picks the full-width register for `{0:r}`

Comment: @PeterCordes `r` of `{0:r}` specifies the size of the register as 64-bit. What I surprised is that using a 16-bit register causes a general protection fault.

Comment: re: `push di`: like I explained, `retf` pops 16 bytes (and ignores the high 6 of the qword containing the segment selector). https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret  That will misalign the stack and break the rest of your code if you only pushed 8 + 2 instead of 8 + 8 bytes.  Or are you saying retf *itself* causes a GPF?  That seems unlikely.  If you're curious, use a debugger to see which instruction actually GPFs after you mess up the stack.

Comment: In GAS `.intel_syntax`, the syntax for `push` with the address as an absolute 32-bit-sign-extended immediate would be `push OFFSET 1f`, but that doesn't seem to work in Rust https://godbolt.org/z/hznEbs :/ Neither does AT&T syntax `push $1f`, unsurprising because this isn't AT&T syntax.  BTW, if you are going to LEA, use `[rip + 1f]` instead of absolute `1f`; it's smaller code size.

Comment: Have you tried AT&T syntax mode?  https://github.com/Amanieu/rfcs/blob/inline-asm/text/0000-inline-asm.md says one exists, which might make `pushq $1f` work.  Obviously it would be nicer to still use Intel syntax, although it seems to be a MASM-like flavour, like GAS / LLVM `.intel_syntax`, not NASM-like.

Comment: The docs I found explicitly say it's supposed to be using GAS / LLVM style `.intel_syntax noprefix`, so I think it's a bug that `push OFFSET 1f` doesn't work.  I'm not sure the best place to report that.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for lots of useful comments. I sent [a bug report](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74558).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rust `asm!` macro is built upon `llvm`.

And there is [a specific bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36144) in llvm that interpret labels only composed of `0` and `1` digits, such as `0`, `11` or `101010`, as binary values. That's what's happening here, this binary value is read as an address in memory.

Also, the rust `asm!` documentation had been updated and now include a [labels section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/library-features/asm.html#labels).

Comment: A comment on that github issue suggested that using `2:` could be a workaround.  But I tested (in a stand-alone `.s` with clang), and [that doesn't work either](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74558#issuecomment-834382267).  So I guess use `.Lfoobar:` and hope your asm doesn't expand twice in the same file, or look for Rust inline asm equivalent to GCC inline asm's `%=` auto-numbered thing for uniquifying things in asm template strings.  [Inline assembly label already defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31529224)